# Are black bikes really stolen more than other colors?

Tags: theft

Is there any evidence that thieves prefer one color of bike than others?

I'm not asking for opinion but for a citable reference.

Comment: This comes from a comment @Criggie made in another question.

Comment: Red bikes go faster?  White bikes are frequently dirty?  I'd wonder if there's a relationship between people who wear a lot of black, would choose to ride a black bike over any other colour, and then perhaps not lock it up as much as someone riding a different colour?   <br> Totally subjectve impression based on riders who wear all black+no lights at night+remove reflectors+no mandated helmet (in NZ)  and bonus points for riding on the wrong side of the road, on the footpath, or are using a cellphone while riding :-\

Comment: Last time I traveled I told my travel companion that black bikes must be very popular in that town. In the whole (Germany and Denmark) travel I did see more black bikes than all other colours combined. I am pretty sure a high percentage of stolen bikes will be black as well. (I do not claim black bikes are more popular there, it was just the impression I got.)

Comment: We might count if there are more requests to identify black bikes here on SE.

Comment: @Willeke - Actually, all the bikes you saw were stolen.  It's a very dishonest town.

Comment: I'd guess there are (many) more black bikes to begin with, followed by white and red. I doubt anyone has actually run/collected numbers on the distribution of bikes stolen by color (or even the number of bikes sold by each color).

Comment: Now you mention it, I've owned five bikes as an adult: three of them were black and two of those were stolen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finding statistics is extremely difficult, but one set of data was located from the [Chicago Stolen Bike Registry](http://chicago.stolenbike.org).

Their [statistics page](http://chicago.stolenbike.org/report-statistics) is now dead/404-ed but if you go to the WaybackMachine, you can get [archived data from September 2012](http://web.archive.org/web/20120904165633/http://chicago.stolenbike.org:80/report-statistics).

And tada!

> This one is probably a bit less than scientific, but seemed interesting.
> Also, unlike all of our other stats, it's based on a free-form text entry,
> rather than a select-box type field.
>
> | Color | Percentage |
> | --- | --- |
> | Black | 14.23% |
> | blue | 7.60% |
> | Red | 5.28% |
> | Silver | 5.21% |
> | White | 4.87% |
> | Green | 2.30% |
> | Grey | 1.63% |
> | Yellow | 1.26% |
> | Light Blue | 1.17% |
> | ORANGE | 1.15% |
> | Gray | 1.09% |
> | purple | 0.91% |
> | Gold | 0.83% |
> | Black/Silver | 0.80% |
> | Brown | 0.74% |
> | dark blue | 0.74% |

However, to make sense of this data we'd also have to know what proportion of colors are the most popular amongst bike **sales** because if Black bikes make up 25% of the market but only 14% of thefts, then black bikes would be proportionately **less likely** to be stolen. So some further research is needed.

---

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't find any data on the popularity of bicycle colors (especially in Chicago :-)

Comment: I guess the distribution of colours bought will be largely independent of location, so if anyone can find any data, it's probably not very important that it be for Chicago.

Comment: Anyone with pictures of bike racks in Chicago circa 2012, please share!

Comment: I don't care enough about this to dig, but there are a lot of bike sales/use stats compiled here: http://www.ibike.org/library/statistics.htm

Answer (score -4):

Black Colour Bicycle is Bicycle Thief choice is for One reason:

Thief can just paint it with black coloured Spray and Not get detected

Black colour bicycle is the world's Most favorite colour,Even I want it

Black coloured bicycle (Mostly Plain bicycle) Is very common in US

Comment: Black bicycles are definitely not rare. Among other things, the most common bicycle ever made comes primarily in black- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Pigeon

Comment: But if a thief stole a black bicycle.....why would they then want to spray paint it black?

Comment: To make it look like painted? Like a bank robber would wear an obvious fake mustache over real one?

Comment: It will sorta make it less obvious I think